# how to get data after specific string to specific length in linux

Tags: text-processing

consider the below lines

```
842567831752rajfkglxfgk  kerigjeiofjgoe jergjerio4523789573489

genfjkgnerijio 234578934897 jgioefjgio  shfhuwehjdfu7890345289103
```

how do i  get four digits after 789 in the above lines in linux

Comment: Which ones? All of them? The 4 digits after the *first* `789` on each line? What if there are fewer than 4 digits afterwards? What if there are non-digits afterwards? What output do you expect from this example?

Comment: Also, do the four digits have to be contiguous?

Answer (score 2):

## Use grep

```
grep -Po '(?<=789).{4}'
```

#### Explanation

- `grep -P`: use grep in Perl mode
- `-o`: only return the matching part
- `(?<=789)`: lookbehind. This should come before the "matching" part.
- `.{4}`: match four characters (after the lookbehind). This is what will be returned.

## Or use sed

```
sed -r 's/.*789(.{4}).*/\1/'
```

This assumes that there is only one `789` in the line.

#### Explanation

- `sed -r`: use sed in extended regular expression mode for better readability.
- `s/foo/bar/`: replace `foo` with `bar`.
- `.*789(.{4}).*`: match the beginning of the line `.*`, `789`, then four characters `(.{4})`, while capturing them with `()`, then the rest of the line `.*`. This matches the whole line in total.
- `\1`: replace the whole line with the first matching pattern from above.

## Or use awk

```
awk '{if (match($0,/789(.{4})/,m)) print m[1]}'
```

This assumes that there is only one `789` in the line. There are probably half a dozen ways to do this in awk.

#### Explanation

- `match($0,/789(.{4})/,m)`: look in the whole line `$0` for the regex `789(.{4})`, and capture the four characters after `789`.
- `print m[1]`: print the first capturing group.

## Just digits

If you only want to pick up digits, then you could use something like the following:

```
grep -Po '(?<=789).*' | sed -r 's/^[^0-9]*([0-9])[^0-9]*([0-9])[^0-9]*([0-9])[^0-9]*([0-9]).*/\1\2\3\4/'
```

Note that this strategy presumes that there *are* four digits after `789`.

### Explanation

- `grep -Po '(?<=789).*'`: similar to above, but output *all* characters after `789`.
- `| sed -r 's/foo/bar/'`: pipe it to sed using extended regular expression mode and replacing `foo` with `bar.
- `^[^0-9]*([0-9])[^0-9]*([0-9])[^0-9]*([0-9])[^0-9]*([0-9]).*`: match the beginning of the line `^`, all non-digit characters `[^0-9]*`, then capture the digit `([0-9])`. Repeat this three more times, then match the remainder of the line `.*`.
- `\1\2\3\4`: replace the whole line with the capturing groups, i.e. the next four digits.

(Alternatively you could simplify the sed expression by using perl's non-greedy regex. `perl -pe 's/.*?([0-9]).*?([0-9]).*?([0-9]).*?([0-9]).*/\1\2\3\4/'`)

Comment: All of your solutions will find the next 4 *characters* after the target string. The OP asked for *digits*. I asked the OP to clarify since the question is really vague.

Comment: @terdon Updated.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo "842567831752rajfkglxfgk  kerigjeiofjgoe jergjerio4523789573489" | grep -oP '789\K....'
5734
$ echo "genfjkgnerijio 234578934897 jgioefjgio  shfhuwehjdfu7890345289103" | grep -oP '789\K....'
3489
0345
```

Answer (score 0):

**`AWK`** solution to find ALL 4-digit items going after `789`:

```
awk -F'789' '{ for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s",(i==2?"":" "),substr($i,1,4); print ""}' file
```

- `-F'789'` - treating `789` as field separator

---

The output (all found items *per line*):

```
5734
3489 0345
```

**----------**

Or simply print each item on a separate line:

```
awk -F'789' '{ for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print substr($i,1,4) }' file
```

The output:

```
5734
3489
0345
```